# How do I get data from a json file after it has been parsed? (Swift 5)

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing

I have a data.json file containing this,

```
[
    {
        "question": "TEST QUESTIONS",
        "answer" : ["Answer1", "Answer2"],
        "correctAnswer": "Answer "
    },
    {
        "question" : "TEST QUESTION 2",
        "answer" : ["Answer1", "Answer2"],
        "correctAnswer" : "Answer 2"
    }

]
```

And i parse the data with this function

```
func Parser() -> [Questions] {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let questions = try? decoder.decode([Questions].self, from: data)
    return questions!
}
```

When i call `Parser()` how do I get the information such as question or answer, I thought to use `let question = Parser().question` but that doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume you have a class or struct created elsewhere in your code that contains vars for each of your JSON dict keys (i.e. “question”, “answer”, “correcctanswer”) and that that struct is called Questions?

If so, then you can call your Parser function as follows:

```
Let newDataFromJson: [Questions] = Parser()
```

From there, if you want to access the questions instance, you can do that with:

```
newDataFromJson.question
```

Answer (score 1):

Parser()
already returning an Array to You
you can get it by

```
    let questions = Parser()
    for question in questions {
       print("Question: \(question.question), Correct answer: \(question.answer)")
    }
```